# MySql Count cannot show 0 values

Tags: mysql, join, count, zero

I have two tables one
Employee and mailing Subscriptions
Employee looks like this:

Name (pk)  | Surname | Age

mailing Subsriptions

MailId (pk)| EmployeeName (fk)|Description | Date

I wanted to subscription number for each customer, therefore I tried the following query:

```
Select COUNT(c.Name) 
From Employee 
    INNER JOIN mailingSubscriptions as m ON c.Name = m.EmployeeName;
```

It will give me all counts for each Employee that *has* an entry in the mailing subscription.

My problem is that I want to see the counts for ALL the Employees, including the ones without an entry (therefore to show 0), I tried an outer left/right join, but it will not work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT c.name, count(m.mailid)
FROM Employee 
   LEFT JOIN mailingSubscriptions as m ON c.Name = m.EmployeeName
GROUP BY c.name;
```

Comment: O.O I can't believe it I made such a silly mistake! I just realised it now.... OOPS! thank you!